# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Reachability' for swift 5

Tags: unwrap, reachability-swift

I get the warning xcode 11.1 for iOS 13 (swift 5) 
`Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Reachability'` on the line `let reachability = Reachability()!`

I tried, if statements and try do, but none seem to work.Removing the ! gives the warning "Call can throw, but errors cannot be thrown out of a property initializer"

```
import Reachability

class ReachabilityDetect {

   let reachability = Reachability()!

   var dm = DataModel()

   func addObservers(datamodel: DataModel) {
       self.dm = datamodel
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
       do{
           try reachability.startNotifier()
       }catch{
           Util.DLog("Reachability notifier niet te starten.")
       }
   }

   @objc func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {

      let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

       switch reachability.connection {
       case .wifi:
           Util.DLog("WiFi is actief")
           self.dm.dataConnectionisWifi     = true
           self.dm.dataConnectionisCellular = false
       case .cellular:
           Util.DLog("Celluar data is actief")
           self.dm.dataConnectionisWifi     = false
           self.dm.dataConnectionisCellular = true
       case .none:
           Util.DLog("geen celluar of wifi data actief")
           self.dm.dataConnectionisWifi     = false
           self.dm.dataConnectionisCellular = false
       default: break
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Instead of

```
let reachability = Reachability()!
```

use this

```
let reachability = try! Reachability()
```